# Python pandas: create new column based on category values from another dataframe

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, categories

I have two dataframes:

- `dfA`, which contains thousands of lines of temperature data. Each temperature value is linked to a `timeID` value (1, 2, 3, ..., n) measured from different objects, so that there are repeated time IDs
- `dfB` contains labels identifying each time ID. These labels are proper date/time (`date`) values

Now, I would like to create a new column in `dfA`, which contains the correct `date`value corresponding to the right `timeID`. How can I achieve this?

Here are a few lines of the datasets I have, as an example:

```
dfA = pd.DataFrame({'timeID': ['1', '2', '3','2','3','4'], 'temp': ['4.5', '5.1', '4.0','-2.3','3.9','-1.1']})
dfB = pd.DataFrame(pd.date_range('6/24/2013', periods=6, freq='10Min'))
seq = pd.Series(range(1, 7)).to_frame()
dfB = pd.concat([seq,dfB],axis=1)
dfB.columns = ['timeID','date']
dfB.set_index('timeID',inplace=True)
print(dfA)
print(dfB)
```

The output for `dfA` is:

```
|    temp  timeID
+-----------------
| 0   4.5      1
| 1   5.1      2
| 2   4.0      3
| 3  -2.3      2
| 4   3.9      3
| 5  -1.1      4
```

The output for `dfB`is:

```
|                      date
| timeID                    
+----------------------------
| 1      2013-06-24 00:00:00
| 2      2013-06-24 00:10:00
| 3      2013-06-24 00:20:00
| 4      2013-06-24 00:30:00
| 5      2013-06-24 00:40:00
| 6      2013-06-24 00:50:00
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all you will need to make sure that the `timeID` column is of the same dtype in both DFs and then you can use [map()](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.map.html) method:

```
In [78]: dfA['date'] = dfA['timeID'].astype(dfB.index.dtype).map(dfB['date'])

In [79]: dfA
Out[79]:
   temp timeID                date
0   4.5      1 2013-06-24 00:00:00
1   5.1      2 2013-06-24 00:10:00
2   4.0      3 2013-06-24 00:20:00
3  -2.3      2 2013-06-24 00:10:00
4   3.9      3 2013-06-24 00:20:00
5  -1.1      4 2013-06-24 00:30:00
```

It also makes sense to convert `timeID` dtype in a smaller DF as it will be faster (more effective), so if `dfB` is smaller I would do it this way:

```
In [82]: dfB.index = dfB.index.astype(str)

In [84]: dfA['date'] = dfA['timeID'].map(dfB['date'])

In [85]: dfA
Out[85]:
   temp timeID                date
0   4.5      1 2013-06-24 00:00:00
1   5.1      2 2013-06-24 00:10:00
2   4.0      3 2013-06-24 00:20:00
3  -2.3      2 2013-06-24 00:10:00
4   3.9      3 2013-06-24 00:20:00
5  -1.1      4 2013-06-24 00:30:00
```

Comment: Awesome! Thank you so much! I have converted `timeID` dtype as you suggested in your second option - and it works pretty well!

Comment: @mmeclimate, glad i could help. ;)

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dfNew = dfA.join(dfB, on='timeID')
```

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. This gives me the following output: `temp timeID date
0   4.5      1  NaT
1   5.1      2  NaT
2   4.0      3  NaT
3  -2.3      2  NaT
4   3.9      3  NaT
5  -1.1      4  NaT`